How to force a set partitioning constraint to "become redundant" or "not require"?
I am an network engineer and currently I have to deal with an optimization problem that have set partition constraint with a very specific requirement:
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {Min}\limits_x }&{f\left( x \right)}\\
{{c_1}:}&{{x_1} + {x_2} = 1}\\
{{c_2}:}&{{x_2} + {x_3} = 1}\\
{{c_3}:}&{{x_4} + {x_5} = {y_1}}\\
{{c_4}:}&{{x_5} + {x_6} = {y_2}}\\
{}&{{x_1},{x_2},{x_3},{x_4},{x_5},{x_6} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}\\
{}&{{y_1},{y_2} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Constraints}}}&{{\rm{Control}}\,\,{\rm{Variables}}}\\
{{c_1}}&{{t_1}}\\
{{c_2}}&{{t_2}}\\
{{c_3}}&{{t_3}}\\
{{c_4}}&{{t_4}}
\end{array}$
Here $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4 \in \{0,1\}$ with the rule ${t_i} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0,}&{{c_i}\,{\rm{become }}\,{\rm{redundant}}}\\
{1,}&{{{\rm{enforce }}\, {\rm{ constraint }}\,{c_i}}}
\end{array}} \right.$
I guess this can be done by some Boolean logic trick but I cannot come up with a general way to come up with a reformulation. Would you kindly help me with this ?

I think you mean "relaxed" rather than "redundant".

If I’m not mistaken, this might be a good opportunity for constraint programming. Much easier to solve sudoku-type problems with CP than IP

@jbuddy_13 Oh I dont know what is this constraint programming thing that you are mentioning about. Can you make it into an answer so that our community can benefit and learn from your great expertise ?

@TuongNguyenMinh - https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp for a application (rather than theory) oriented introduction

You can rewrite $c_3$ and $c_4$ as set partitioning by a change of variables $\bar{y}_i=1-y_i$. For example, $c_3$ becomes $x_4+x_5+\bar{y}_1=1$.
You want to enforce $$t_i=1 \implies \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j = 1.$$ Either directly use an indicator constraint or linearize via big-M:
$$-(1-t_i) \le \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j - 1 \le (|J_i|-1)(1-t_i)$$
Equivalently,
$$t_i \le \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j \le |J_i|-(|J_i|-1)t_i \tag1\label1$$
For example, your $c_1$ has $J_1=\{1,2\}$, yielding $$t_1 \le \sum_{j\in \{1,2\}} x_j \le 2-(2-1)t_1$$
Similarly, your $c_3$ yields
$$t_3 \le x_4+x_5+(1-y_1) \le 3-(3-1)t_3$$

Here's an alternative approach via conjunctive normal form.  You want to enforce the logical proposition
$$t_i \implies \left(\bigvee_{j\in J_i} x_j \land \bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} \lnot(x_j \land x_k)\right).$$
Equivalently,
$$
\lnot t_i \lor \left(\bigvee_{j\in J_i} x_j \land \bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} \lnot(x_j \land x_k)\right) \\
\lnot t_i \lor \left(\bigvee_{j\in J_i} x_j \land \bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} (\lnot x_j \lor \lnot x_k)\right) \\
\left(\lnot t_i \lor \bigvee_{j\in J_i} x_j\right) \land 
\left(\bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} (\lnot t_i \lor \lnot x_j \lor \lnot x_k)\right) \\
\left((1-t_i) + \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j \ge 1\right) \land 
\left(\bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} ((1-t_i) + (1-x_j) + (1-x_k)\ge 1)\right) \\
\left(\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j \ge t_i\right) \land 
\left(\bigwedge_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} (t_i + x_j + x_k \le 2)\right) $$
That is,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j &\ge t_i \tag2\label2 \\
t_i + x_j + x_k &\le 2 &&\text{for all $\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Note that \eqref{2} is the same as the first inequality in \eqref{1}.
Aggregating \eqref{3} yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} (t_i + x_j + x_k) &\le \sum_{\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i} 2 \\
\binom{|J_i|}{2} t_i + (|J_i|-1) \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j &\le 2 \binom{|J_i|}{2} \\
\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j &\le |J_i| - \frac{|J_i|}{2} t_i
\end{align}
This aggregation is weaker than the second inequality in \eqref{1} when $|J_i| - 1 \ge \frac{|J_i|}{2}$, that is, when $|J_i| \ge 2$, which is the only case of interest.

For small $|J_i|\ge 2$, PORTA returns the following formulation with $2^{|J_i|} + |J_i| + 1$ constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j &\ge t_i \\
\sum_{j\in K} x_j &\le |K| - (|K|-1)t_i &&\text{for $K \subseteq J_i$} \\
x_j &\ge 0 &&\text{for $j\in J_i$}
\end{align}
Note that $|K|=0$ yields $t_i \ge 0$ and $|K|=1$ yields $x_j \le 1$.

Actually what I mean is that all $x_i \in {0,1}$. Sorry about that ! Also, what is this big $J_i$

may I ask which one provide stronger relaxation: the conjunctive normal form in (2) and (3) or the Big M constraint in (1)

For $|J_i|=2$, the two formulations are identical.  For $|J_i|=3$, neither one dominates the other; it would be a good exercise to find two fractional solutions that each satisfy exactly one of the two sets of constraints.

Thank you so much ! this is so outstanding
